# Error on invoke when the form has closed already

Tags: c#, winforms, invoke, multithreading, begininvoke

I am trying to display some information on a grid queried from a sql server. The data gathering can take about 10 seconds so I don't want to lock the UI thread.

I currently have code like:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DataUpdateThread, new UpdateParams(year));  

private struct UpdateParams
{
    internal string year;

    internal UpdateParams(string year)
    {
        this.year = year;
    }
}

private void DataUpdateThread(object state)
{
    DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            //stop data editing on the grid
            //scrolling marquee for user
            marquee.Visible = true;
            marquee.Enabled = true;
            grdMain.Visible = false;
            grdMain.DataSource = null;
        });

            UpdateParams parameters = (UpdateParams)state;            
            dTable = GetData(parameters.year);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            //log error + end user message
        });
    }
    finally
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            grdMain.DataSource = dTable;
            grdMainLevel1.RefreshData();
            marquee.Visible = false;
            marquee.Enabled = false;
            grdMain.Visible = true;
        });
   }
}
```

This works most of the time apart from if the form it is on is closed before the update completes it will crash with the error:

> Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.

I understand the error will be because the form no longer exists so when the finally section tries to invoke the method on the UI thread it can't.

Is there a better way to do this whole thing? I guess I can handle the invoke errors but it looks messy and I think I have probably missed a simpler way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check whether the form has been closed and don't do the invoke if the form has been closed. `if (this.IsHandleCreated)` should work. This can however still give problems because the form can be closed between the check and the call to `BeginInvoke`. The only 'full-proof' solution is then to enclose the entire call in a try/catch.

Comment: Thanks that solved it. Out of curiosity is their likely any difference between the two properties? I guess the form handle is created when the form is and disposed of at the same time.

Comment: You should `IsHandleCreated` because `Invoke` will only work after the form has been shown. Before the show, you get the exception too.

Comment: This will give you a nasty hard to reproduce bug.  Consider what happens when the form ceases to exist after the check passes but you are still in the if block.

Comment: try/catch. That's probably the only 'full-proof' solution.

Comment: This doesn't actually work reliably.  There's an unsolvable race condition, the form could get destroyed between the calls to IsHandleCreated and Invoke().  Small odds, not zero.

Comment: @Hans Passant - Yep, that's why a try/catch probably will be the only thing that's going to work reliably.

Comment: But testing IsHandleCreated in the invoked code should be okay.

Comment: It will minimize the chance of exceptions from the `BeginInvoke`, but will **not** guarantee they won't occur.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `InvokeRequired()` before `Invoke()`

Answer (score 1):

`Invoke` uses a special WinForms `SynchronizationContext` behind the scenes that you can access with `SynchronizationContext.Current` anywhere in your app.

**CORRECTION after some poking in Reflector**: actually Invoke goes the direct way of marshalling via PostMessage, it's the BackgroundWorker that makes use of SynchronizationContext behind the scenes. Invoke will throw if it does not have a window handle.

Basically you need to store it in a variable before you start the thread, e.g. while you're still in your UI thread, and use `Post` or `Send` method of the context in the thread's code. Doing so will marshal the stuff properly without window handles.